# Is there any way to compare latency between request from asia and request from US both to ec2 server in private subnet?

Tags: amazon-ec2, latency, private-subnet

Is there any way to compare latency between request from asia and request from US both to ec2 server in private subnet?

I need to compare a latency when I request in korea and also in US.
The ec2 server is in private subnet and have private ip.

Hope you guys let me know if there's any tool to test latency or how to do it. Thank you :)

- Searched if there's any tool to test latency in aws.
- Searched how to check latency in public ip.